# jBCrypt String index out of range: 0 error on starting app in Netbeans

Tags: java, jbcrypt

I'm receiving the following error in the Apache logs when starting my application

I've found [BCrypt.checkpw() Invalid salt version exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478604/bcrypt-checkpw-invalid-salt-version-exception)
But this is not a match as the passwords stored in the DB for my users are hashed and this error appears on start up and I've no issues logging in 99.99% of the time.

```
29-Oct-2017 22:12:32.242 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for     servlet [UserController] in context with path [/medsched] threw exception
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:658)
at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.checkpw(BCrypt.java:764)
at medsched.data.UserDB.loginUser(UserDB.java:216)
at medsched.controllers.UserController.logInToSite(UserController.java:165)
at medsched.controllers.UserController.doPost(UserController.java:41)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at medsched.filters.SecPageFilter.doFilter(SecPageFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

It does not seem to affect the application as nearly most of the time as I can log in or if I present a password mismatch I am returned to a login error jsp defined in my application. I do some times, however receive a 500 error page with

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:658)
at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.checkpw(BCrypt.java:764)
at medsched.data.UserDB.loginUser(UserDB.java:216)
at   medsched.controllers.UserController.logInToSite(UserController.java:165)
at medsched.controllers.UserController.doPost(UserController.java:41)
```

Could it be the way I'm using BCrypt.checkpw ?? I'd understand the error appearing if I was attempting to log in, but not on starting the application in Netbeans.

```
public static User loginUser(String phnum,String passw) {
    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String hpwd="";

    //Get the key 
    String key=confUtil.encDeckey();

     String query = "SELECT userid,fName,pwd FROM users "
           + "WHERE  phone = AES_ENCRYPT(?,?) AND active=1";
    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, phnum);
        ps.setString(2, key);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        User user = null;
        if (rs.next()) {
            user = new User();
            user.setUserID(rs.getLong("userid"));
            user.setFName(rs.getString("fName"));
            user.setPwd(rs.getString("pwd"));
           hpwd=user.getPwd();
        }
        if(hpwd!=null || !hpwd.isEmpty()){
            if(!BCrypt.checkpw(passw,hpwd)){
            user=null;
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //System.err.println(e);
        log.error("Exception when trying to log in",e);

        return null;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }
}
```

Issue occurred again today, posting the 500 error that I'm getting

HTTP Status 500 - String index out of range: 0
type Exception report

```
message String index out of range: 0

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:658)
org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.checkpw(BCrypt.java:764)
medsched.data.UserDB.loginUser(UserDB.java:190)
medsched.controllers.UserController.logInToSite(UserController.java:169)
medsched.controllers.UserController.doPost(UserController.java:41)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
  org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
 org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
 medsched.filters.SecPageFilter.doFilter(SecPageFilter.java:61)
        org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)

 note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 logs.
```

Comment: Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue:

Bcrypt throws `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0`.

In my case I found out that the hashed password was empty.

I can't tell why this error is appearing at app start without seeing more code.